# ODE, change of form and unsolvable unknown

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, laplace-transform

So I have tried many methods including Laplace transform and differentiation but the p and q seems to be unsolvable, I would like to know how does the form change from the first equation, then substitude the Y = e^t to get the second equation. also my second question is why is how can i solve for p and q if i dont have any initial conditions?[image]

Comment: Seems to be the Euler equation. See wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation and web ...

Comment: it seems the same but i cant see how to change it

Comment: $\int_0^\infty g(x) dx = \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_0^b g(x) dx$ is a valid definition for any function $g$, if the limit on the right hand side doesn't exist the improper integral doesn't exist. That's all

Comment: Now plug in $g(x) = e^{px} f(x)$

Comment: Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a positive measurable function. If $f\leq 1$ almost everywhere and $f\geq 1$ almost everywhere (with respect to lebesgue measure). Show that $f=1_{A}$ for some $A\in B[0,1]$.
?

Comment: try showing that if $x=e^t$ that $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=x$ and thus, $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}=x\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$. Furthermore, $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2}=x^2\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}+x\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$.

Comment: @JosephRock plugging into the integral definition you get $F(0)=\int_0^\infty \cos(ax)dx$, does that converge?

Comment: try showing that if $x=e^t$ that $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=x$ and thus, $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}=x\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$. Furthermore, $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2}=x^2\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}+x\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$. This also means that $x^2\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}=\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2}-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}$. Apply this to $Y(t)=y(x)$.

Comment: Your question about $p$ and $q$ makes no sense. You're not supposed to solve for them, they are just some given numbers.